# $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is an infinite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to prove that $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is an infinite abelian group, the easiest part is to prove that this set is an abelian group, I'm trying so hard to prove that this group is infinite without success.

This set is defined to be equivalences classes of $\mathbb Q$, where $x\sim y$ iff $x-y\in \mathbb Z$.

I need help here.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove that if $x,y\in[0,1)\cap\Bbb Q$, then $x\sim y$ if and only if $x=y$.

Comment: Very clever, really elegant solution, I'm trying to prove it right now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's the analogue from proving that Vitali sets are uncountable. :-)

Comment: That's "" simple "", @AsafKaragila : just prove the Vitali set is not measurable...:)

Comment: @DonAntonio: Trick question! There are no Vitali sets in Solovay's model! ;-)

Comment: My heart bleeds for Solovay's model, which fortunately enough I've never heard of (is that something from logic? If so pass it over to Sharon Shelakh: not for me)

Comment: @DonAntonio: It was the model constructed by Robert Solovay in which he proved the consistency of $\sf ZF+DC+\text{every set of reals is measurable}$. In those models there are no Vitali sets. Also, I was warned not to ask (Saharon, not Sharon) Shelah questions because he will solve them before I get the chance, so I'm heeding that advice so far... :-)

Comment: I've already proved using your hint and one of the answers below using primes, I'm trying to adapt the solution using primes below to prove your hint, do you know if this is possible? since we can decompose every integer as primes factors. Nonetheless I didn't have any progress using this strategy.

Comment: @user42912: Suppose that $x-y\in\Bbb Z$, then $|x-y|\in\Bbb Z$, but $|x-y|<1$ because $x,y\in[0,1)$. Therefore $|x-y|=0$.

Comment: I know it is pronounced Saharon, yet it is (or was, in fact) written exactly the same as Sharon (שרון), though right now I checked in the school's page and they now write it שהרן...a mess.

Comment: @DonAntonio: The Hebrew writing is completely different. The name, if I recall correctly, means a Canaanite preying beads or something like that. When I first heard it I thought it was written סהרון which would translate roughly as "little moon"...

Comment: Saharon (let's transliterate the name as he pronounces it) is a shomroni, if I recall correctly. The first one I wrote above is how I saw it written first time while reading the shnaton some 25 years or so ago, and the second one how it is written now in the Institute's page. BTW, many called him, and perhaps even now, Sharon.

Answer (score 4):

Look at $[1/n]$ in this equivalence class for $n\ge 2$ These are all distinct mod $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit more background: $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a nontrivial [divisible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group) abelian group. The only finite divisible abelian group is the trivial group (else you cannot divide by the group order by Lagrange).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a question where there many ways to solve it. The quickest I could come up with:

Count the prime numbers: $p_1, p_2, p_3,\ldots$. Now look at the equivalence classes of $\frac{1}{p_i}$ in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. For $i\neq j$ we have that $\frac{1}{p_i}-\frac{1}{p_j}=\frac{p_j-p_i}{p_ip_j}$. If this were an integer, say $n$, we would see that $p_j-p_i = np_ip_j$, or equivalently $p_j=p_i(1+np_j)$. This is somewhat impossible and so the difference is no element of $\mathbb{Z}$. This proves that all equivalence classes of $\frac{1}{p_i}$ are different. Therefore, there must be infinitely many elements in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you, using primes makes the solution simpler.

Comment: It doesn't make it simpler, it makes it more complicated. All the $\overline{1/n}$ are pairwise distinct, by a simple distance argument, and we don't need that $n$ is prime.

Comment: The thought of using a distance argument simply hadn't occured to me, last night. I agree that it is a far simpler one. I'm nonetheless glad that one can live without needing the concept of distance here.

Answer (score 1):

Another hint: prove that for

$$n,k\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;n\neq k\;,\;\;\;\frac{1}{n}+\Bbb Z\neq\frac{1}{k}+\Bbb Z$$

Comment: Of course. Thanks]

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, you can think of the quotient of $\mathbb{Q}$ by $\mathbb{Z}$ as fractions in an interval from $0$ to $1$.  What you're doing when you quotient by $\mathbb{Z}$ is you set each integer to be $0$ - it's the rationals "mod 1."

To easily argue that the group is infinite, notice the fact that $\frac{1}{s}\mathbb{Z}=\frac{1}{r}\mathbb{Z} \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{t}\in\mathbb{Z}$.  To verify my interpretation of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is true, compare two arbitrary $x\mathbb{Z},y\mathbb{Z}$ with $0\leq x,y<1$.

Answer (score 1):

The map $\rho: \mathbb{R} \to S^1,\;t \mapsto e^{2\pi\text{i}t}$ is  a surjective homomorphism of groups with kernel $\mathbb{Z}$. Hence $\rho(\mathbb{Q})$ is the group of roots of unity $\mu$ and $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{\mu}$. In particular, its infinite, since $\mu$ has the infinite subset $\{e^{\frac{2\pi\text{i}}{n}}\mid n \in \mathbb{Z},\;n> 0\}$.

Comment: You could also write directly that $\overline{1/n}$ are distinct in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ without this homomorphism ;).

Comment: Of course, but I wanted to relate the group in question to a group the OP might be more familar with.

Answer (score 1):

By regarding to $\mathbb Z(p^{\infty})$ where in $p\in P$ the set of all prime numbers, it is not hard to see that $$\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\cong \sum_{p\in P} \mathbb Z(p^{\infty})$$

Comment: +1 You were busy at math.se today! That's good for us all ;-)